# TOC in a bilingual paper at arXiv

Tags: table-of-contents, arxiv

I have [one paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.07911.pdf) on arXiv with a translation. 
I followed the instructions [here](https://arxiv.org/help/faq/multilang), and arXiv have made one pdf-file from two tex-files. However, every section in the table of contents (bookmarks) always points to the corresponding  section in the second file.

In my case if you click English section #n, it will bring you the Russian section #n.
The labels for chapters in the tex-files are different, so it is NOT because of labels.

> Is there a trick to make it right?

and more generally:

> How arXiv generates one *.pdf from two standalone article files?

**P.S.** The following line (suggested by [Ulrike Fischer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2388/ulrike-fischer))

```
\renewcommand*{\HyperDestNameFilter}[1]{\jobname-#1}
```

solves the problem.

Comment: It would help to know how ArXiv generates one *.pdf from two 'standalone' article files

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I included your question, hope you do not mind.

Comment: I think what Christian means is that TeX normally processes a single tex file into a single pdf, so you have apparently done something so that arXiv concatenates `english.tex` with `russian.tex`.  Without knowing how you did that, it will be difficult to figure out how arXiv got that particular output.  Is it possible that you have `main.tex` with the sole contents `\input{english}\input{russian}`?  And that the corresponding files are translations of each other, but that you didn't change any labels?

Comment: @Teepeemm right --- this should fix it, but this is not a good solution --- if in the future arXiv will provide two links for two files then I will have just one file instead. (I added a link to a recomendations for Multiple-Language Submissions)

Comment: I don't think you're following, and I'm not understanding what you mean by "this" in your last comment.  You (not arXiv) have done something to make one pdf from two standalone tex files.  Making it right will be a matter of undoing that something.  We can't help you undo that something until you tell us what that something was.

Comment: @Teepeemm: Yes, that's what I meant, but apparently I wrongly assumed that ArXiv is responsible for the merging of the files.

Comment: @Teepeemm I'm not quite sure that's the case. From the arxiv page, "Note that the compiled PDF will combine the different versions into a single PDF file for readers to download." it does seem the combination is done by arxiv. If you download OP's source file from [arxiv](https://arxiv.org/format/1511.07911), there is no `main.tex`, but rather `english.tex` and `russian.tex`, and a common `bib.tex` (containing a `thebibliography` environment).

Comment: @Troy: Yes, I have obtained the source files as well -- the real document files are standalone `article` class files, both compilable. It is unclear yet, how ArXiv combines the input.

Comment: You could try `\renewcommand*{\HyperDestNameFilter}[1]{\jobname-#1}`, to give the destinations in both files unique names.

Comment: What does that mean? Did you try my suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to add to both files

```
\renewcommand*{\HyperDestNameFilter}[1]{\jobname-#1}
```

This gives the destinations in both files unique names which should allow a clean merge.